# How to make c# code automatic formatted in LinqPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

How to make c# code automatic formatted in LinqPad?

I had tried :
Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D to format the entire document.
Ctrl+E, Ctrl+F to format the selection.

None of them work.

```
void Main()
{
    var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    var ran = new System.Random(10);
    var q = from n in ids           orderby ran.Next() select n;
            q.Dump();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, [LINQPad does not support formatting](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1544891-provide-a-format-statement-option-context-menu-ite)

Comment: Ctrl + K, D is the Visual Studio one. Isn't Ctrl + E, F an R# thing?

Comment: Not as of last March - [link](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/232/is-there-plans-for-a-format-document-like-function-as-in-visual-studio-ctrl-k-ctrl-d)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for LINQPad, and is already recorded on another site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQPad doesn't support automatic code formatting at present. This feature is in the pipeline.

Comment: Joe _might_ be aware, but for those who stumble upon this question, auto formatting is supported in the paid version of LINQPad 5.